# Django- Form does not save the given argument

Tags: python, django-forms

I do not why but the line `recording.component=component` in my views.py does not save the component which is given as an argument and I do not understand the reason. The only think that I have in mind is that I am using smart_select. Here is what I have:

My views.py file:

```
def create_recording(request, slug, inspection_id, component_id):
    inspection = get_object_or_404(Inspection, pk=inspection_id)
    plant = get_object_or_404(Plant, slug=slug)
    component=get_object_or_404(Component, pk=component_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RecordingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            recording = form.save(commit=False)
            recording.user = request.user
            recording.plant = plant
            recording.inspection=inspection
            recording.component=component
            recording.save()
            return redirect('data:inspection_detail', slug=plant.slug, inspection_id=inspection.id)
    else:
        form = RecordingForm()
    context = {'form': form, 'plant':plant,'inspection':inspection,}
    template = 'data/create_recording.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

my models.py:

```
class Recording(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inspection = models.ForeignKey(Inspection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    component = models.ForeignKey(Component)
    group = ChainedForeignKey(Group, chained_field="component", chained_model_field="component", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
    failure = ChainedForeignKey(Failure, chained_field="group", chained_model_field="group", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.failure)
```

my forms.py:

```
class RecordingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Recording
        fields = ['group', 'failure',]
```

my html:

```
<a href="{% url 'data:create_recording' slug=plant.slug inspection_id=inspection.id component_id=1 %}">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Chair
     </button>
</a>
<a href="{% url 'data:create_recording' slug=plant.slug inspection_id=inspection.id component_id=2 %}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Table
    </button>
</a>
```

and the html for for my form:

```
    <div class = "col-sm-7">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Add new recording</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form method='POST'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <button type = 'submit' class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my url:

```
url(r'^plants/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/inspection(?P<inspection_id>[0-9]+)/create_recording/(?P<component_id>[0-9]+)$', views.create_recording, name='create_recording'),
```

please let me know if I need to add some more information.

Comment: Please define "does not work", and post the form's template too.

Comment: I mean it does not save the given argument. I edited my question